# Which solver method for solving indicator function in a QP problem

Tags: optimization, step-function

I am trying to solve below QP problem with Heaviside step function: determining z is to make the J(z) function achieve a maximum

$$
    \begin{align}
\min_z J(z)=(\sum_{(x_i,y_i)\in T,y_i=1}  I(y_if(x_i,z))) \times  (\sum_{(x_i,y_i)\in T,y_i=-1}  I(y_if(x_i,z)))\\
\text{where: Heaviside step function: } 
 I(u)=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $u \ge 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $u \lt 0$}
\end{cases} \\
 \text{and:} \\
 f(x,z)= \sum_{x_p \in SV^+,y_p=1}  z_p\alpha_py_p(x.x_p)+\sum_{x_n \in SV^-,y_n=-1}  \alpha_ny_n(x.x_n) +b, \\
SV^+, SV^-,\alpha_n,\alpha_p,x_n,x_p \text{ is constant value}, y_p=1,y_n=-1\\
\end{align}
$$

I have an idea to cross this problem by approximate I to Logistic function, e.g:
$$
\begin{align}
I(u)=\frac{1 }{1+e^{-2ku}}
\text{where a larger k corresponds to a sharper transition at u = 0}
\end{align}
$$
Then I can find z by using Gradient Descent method:

$$
\begin{align}
z_i=z_i^{old} + \eta * \nabla J(z_i^{old}) \\
\text{where } \eta \text{ is learning rate} \\
\end{align}
$$

Could anyone give me a some advices about my above analysis for search z optimal from J(z)?

Thank everyone